# Batch Files - Can you use wildcards ( * or ? ) in variables - not just filenames?

Tags: file, variables, batch-file

The title says it all - If not then: Is there a way to sense a part of a variable?
Take it like this:

```
set /p input=
if %input%==*crap* goto notAllowed
```

Basically, I want it to "sensor" out if it's not allowed. So basically if the "inputted" variable has "crap" in it, then it will goto "NotAllowed". Is this possible? So if I type crapface or supercrapface then they will both goto notallowed. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set "censored=%input:crap=%"
if not "%censored%"=="%input%" goto notallowed
```

should censor out the crap.

Comment: No need for extra variable: `if "%input%" neq "%input:crap=% goto notallowed`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo %input%|find "crap" && goto notAllowed || goto Allowed
```